# Get values from JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to get the VolumeId and State of the Volume attached to the machines using aws API .

Code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require "aws-sdk"
require "rubygems"


list=Aws::EC2::Client.new(region: "us-east-1")
volume=list.describe_volumes()
volumes=%x( aws ec2 describe-volumes --region='us-east-1' )
puts volumes
```

Below is the sample output of the command 
`aws ec2 describe-volumes --region='us-east-1'` . 
Please help to get  VolumeID and state from the below

Sample Output of API(JSON):

```
{
"Volumes": [
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1d", 
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "AttachTime": "2015-02-02T07:31:36.000Z", 
                "InstanceId": "i-bca66353", 
                "VolumeId": "vol-892a2acd", 
                "State": "attached", 
                "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                "Device": "/dev/sda1"
            }
        ], 
        "Encrypted": false, 
        "VolumeType": "gp2", 
        "VolumeId": "vol-892a2acd", 
        "State": "in-use", 
        "Iops": 100, 
        "SnapshotId": "snap-df910966", 
        "CreateTime": "2015-02-02T07:31:36.380Z", 
        "Size": 8
    }, 
 ]
}
```

Comment: If the output you receive is valid json, you should be able to do JSON.parse(volumes)['Volumes'].map {|volume| volume["VolumeId"] } to get an array of volume idw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for getting just the `volume_ids` ->

```
JSON.parse(volumes)['Volumes'].map{|v|v["VolumeId"]}
```

for getting just the `states` ->

```
JSON.parse(volumes)['Volumes'].map{|v|v["state"]}
```

for getting a hash/map with volume-ids as keys and their states as values ->

```
JSON.parse(volumes)['Volumes'].map{|v| [v["VolumeId"],v["state"]] }.to_h
```